# Shortcut for toggling breakpoint in Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

So, I hit a breakpoint in Chrome Dev Tools:

[image: screen-shot]

With <kbd>F8</kbd> I can continue. Is there any keyboard shortcut to remove/toggle away the breakpoint?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>? (It is even listed in the "Sources panel" section of the Settings dialog's "Shortcuts" tab)

Comment: Maybe that was why nobody else bothered asking about it :)

Comment: Perhaps, but I just came a looking for this very answer despite working with Chrome Dev tools for several years. So it must not be *that* obvious. At least that's what I'll tell myself. :-)

Comment: I just found out they have the like of "Sources panel" (today its called "shortcuts") section

Comment: It's called 'Debugger' section

Comment: right.... except that this feature was apparently deemed not useful, and is now broken in the current release ( 85.0.4183.83 (Official Build) (64-bit))